# System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: asp.net, cryptography

I am using cryptography while saving password, encryption works fine but when I decrypt password, some are decrypted but some give this error

System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Encryption code:

```
public string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "H1E2X3A4PE34RKS";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

Decryption code:

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "H1E2X3A4PE34RKS";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Comment: Billy Mays is still alive? And he uses Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can any one help ????????????????????????????????????

Comment: With what you provided the best i could do is guess that it might have something to with this line cipherText.Replace("+"," "). Any explanation of why this is added or do you have a sample string that's failing.

Comment: I have replace cipherText.Replace("+"," "). Now new error is coming

Comment: What is your new error?  Also, have you displayed the Base64 that is causing the problem and checked it for problems?  All correct Base64 strings should be a multiple of 4 characters long (though some do omit the trailing '=').